# pos_hit do not move along the y-axis and i dont seem to know why

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

So, i've been trying to position a label in my kv file but it only moves along the x-axis with this code:

```
<HomePage>:

    md_bg_color: [34/255, 0/255, 64/255, 1]
    background_normal: ''


    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDBoxLayout:
            padding: '5dp'
            adaptive_height: True

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Shop'
            bold: True
            font_size: 50
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            background_normal: ''
            color: [0/255, 186/255, 198/255, 1]
            pos_hint: {'x':.13, 'y':.18}


        MDTextField:
            mode: 'round'
            text: 'username'
```

i dont understand how this is posible.

Comment: i think i figured it out already. took out the Boxlayout and it worked perfectly

Comment: Consider making this an answer as soon as you can.